# VueJS <b-modal> inside component won't open on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-tables-2

I use `vue-tables-2` and `bootstrap-vue`. I've created a component which is a column in `vue-tables-2` and it consists of button and modal code.

The problem is that this way, the modal is not opening when you click on the button and I don't know why.

**EDIT**

I found out that when I hardcode buttons attribute,it works. It just doesn't work when `v-b-modal.modal-something` is generated by `vue`.

This is a component:

```
 Vue.component('vue-tables-2-product', {
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        props: ['data', 'index', 'column'],
        template: `<div>
                <b-modal v-bind="modal_attrs" title="BootstrapVue">
                    <p class="my-4">[[ this.data.name ]]</p>
                </b-modal>
                <b-button @click="log" v-bind="button_attrs">Detail</b-button></div>`,
        methods: {
            log: function () {
          console.log(this.data)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            button_attrs() {
                return {
                    [`v-b-modal.modal-${this.data.id}`]: "",
                }
            },

            modal_attrs() {
                return {
                    [`id`]: "modal-"+this.data.id,
                }
            },


        }

    })
```

And this is templates from the `vue` app.

```
templates: {
        on_stock: 'boolean',
        is_active: 'boolean',
        name: 'vue-tables-2-product',
        import_export_price_diff: 'vue-tables-2-difference'
}
```

Do you know where is the problem?

EDIT:

I also tried to add `this.$bvModal.show(this.data.id)` into the `log` function and nothing happens.

I noticed that

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you passing empty string as your ID?
What's the reason of doing this?

```
button_attrs() {
  return {
    [`v-b-modal.modal-${this.data.id}`]: "",
  }
},
```

It's literally :v-b-modal.modal-some-id=""

This dot might be problematic tho.

Comment: The problem is that it just doesn't work that way so I used normal button and @onclick this.$bvModal.show("modal-"+this.data.id) - now it works. I forgot to add "modal-" to tho argument :)

Answer (score 0):

Vue accepts variables as modifiers on directives (by placing them in square brackets):

```html
<div>
  <b-modal v-bind="modal_attrs" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">[[ this.data.name ]]</p>
  </b-modal>
  <b-button @click="log" v-b-modal.[modal_attrs.id]>Detail</b-button>
</div>
```